# Is it possible to override the crate-type specified in Cargo.toml from the command line when calling cargo build?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to generate a static library from a Rust project that I do not maintain. The project allows building a dynamic library — the Cargo.toml specifies `crate-type = ["cdylib"]`.

Modifying the crate type in the file works, but I want to keep the unmodified original project as git submodule in my project if possible.

Is there is any flag that can be passed to the `cargo build` command to override this setting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't override it, but you can *supplement* it. Use [`cargo rustc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-rustc.html) and pass `--crate-type=staticlib` directly to the compiler:

```
% cargo build
   Compiling example v0.1.0 (/private/tmp/example)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.31s

% find target -name '*.a'

% cargo rustc -- --crate-type=staticlib
   Compiling example v0.1.0 (/private/tmp/example)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.29s

% find target -name '*.a'
target/debug/deps/libexample.a
```

Comment: Thank you. First of all this works for me (I'm actually calling `cargo rustc --release -- --crate-type=staticlib` now), I find the static lib in target/release/deps. Still I have to admit that as a C++ programer with few rust experience I'm not sure what this call is actually doing or not doing in contrast to `cargo build`? Besides respecting the crate-type I pass to it, will it still use the `Cargo.toml` to e.g. figure out dependencies and other settings found there that I might or might not fully understand right now? Why do I find the generated library in a different destination folder now?

Comment: @PluginPenguin I've added a link to the docs for `cargo rustc`. TL;DR — you can use it to pass more flags to the final invocation of `rustc` that Cargo would make. Yes, dependencies will still be honored. I don't fully understand why the output remains in the `deps` directory, but I _think_ that Cargo always builds into there and then links / copies to the "expected" output location. That copy is skipped here.

Comment: [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/command-line-arguments.html#--crate-type-a-list-of-types-of-crates-for-the-compiler-to-emit) says "The --crate-type command-line value will override the crate_type attribute" so either this answer is deprecated or the documentation is incorrect

Comment: When I try that, I run into tons of errors because then all dependencies are also built as type `staticlib` and this causes error when trying to use them (`crate: ... required to be available in rlib format, but was not found in this form`). Specifying both, `staticlib` and `rlib` also doesn't solve this. Modifying the `Cargo.toml` works fine, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide the `crate-type`, but you cannot override the one specified in your `Cargo.toml`:

```
$ cargo rustc -- --crate-type=staticlib
Compiling example v0.1.0 (/dev/tmp)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.34s
```

There is an [tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/10083) to add a `--crate-type` override. In the meantime, a workaround is to use [`cargo-crate-type`](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-crate-type):

```
$ cargo install cargo-crate-type

$ cargo crate-type static
$ cargo build
```

*Note that this command will alter your `Cargo.toml`*

Answer (score 0):

[Since Rust 1.64](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/cargo/reference/unstable.html#crate-type) it is possible to *override* the crate-type for libraries and examples. Please note the missing `--` compared to the other answers. The `--crate-type` flag in this answer is a [`cargo rustc` flag](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/cargo/commands/cargo-rustc.html#compilation-options), while in the other answers `cargo rustc` was used to pass an *additional* flag to `rustc` (as opposed to replacing the flag like `cargo rustc` does).

```bash
$ cargo rustc --crate-type=staticlib
```